# Can't install Skype from partner repository

Tags: 16.04, skype

I'm a new user to Ubuntu and Linux, and I'm trying to install Skype. The software manager is starting but then canceling without any report, I tried doing it through the terminal using:

```
echo "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/canonical_partner.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```

And some other methods, but I always get the same error every time:

```
E: Unable to locate package skype
```

I checked the Canonical reps, and I really have no idea what am I doing wrong here?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and I just tried to follow various threads, but reached the same dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Skype isn't available from the Ubuntu repositories. To install it on a 64-bit system, open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run:

```
wget https://repo.skype.com/latest/skypeforlinux-64.deb
sudo apt install ./skypeforlinux-64.deb
rm skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

Comment: stuck on 83% should i start again?

Comment: @ShaiFischer If it works, please click the check mark next to this question so that the site knows the question is solved.

Comment: still stuck, 83% and not moving

Comment: `wget` gets stuck sometimes. Press Ctrl+C in that terminal to quit `wget`, run `rm skypeforlinux-64.deb` to remove the partial file, and try again.

Comment: Ctrl+C doesnt seems to do anything hehe

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+C should show a new prompt (looks like `username@computername:~$`) just under the `wget` output. If it does, follow my last comment. If it doesn't, `wget` must have badly frozen up. To solve that, close the terminal window, telling it that it's OK to kill the running process, then open a new terminal window by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, run `rm skypeforlinux-64.deb` to remove the partial file, and try again.

Comment: Thank you for all your devoted help! it works great now!